# A convergent sum of a divergent and convergent sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Is the following argument correct?

> Sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$, where $(x_n)$ converges, $(y_n)$
>   diverges, and $(x_n+y_n)$ converges.

*Proof.* The request in question is impossible. Assume that we have sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ such that $(x_n)\to \alpha$, $(y_n)$ diverges and yet $(x_n+y_n)\to\beta$ where $x,\alpha\in\mathbf{R}$.

Then by combining the first two propositions of theorem $\textbf{2.3.3}$ we have $\lim(y_n) = \lim((x_n+y_n)-x_n) = \beta-\alpha$, contradicting our assumption that $(y_n)$ was not convergent.

$\blacksquare$

**Note:** The propositions in question are that Given $(a_n)\to a$ and $(b_n)\to b$ it follows that $\lim ca_n = ca,\forall c\in\mathbf{R}$ and $\lim(a_n+b_n) = \lim a_n+\lim b_n$

Comment: Correct. The same with a sum of a rational $q$ and irrational $x$, which is irrational. If $q+x$ were rational, then $x=(q+x)-q$ was rational as a difference of two rationals, a contradiction.

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Thankyou all for you responses